# Download shape files from OSM via overpass API

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shapes

What is the way to download shape data centered around the given longitude and latitude coordinates (for example 1000 images from 1000 different locations)? Is there a way to automate that process in python using overpy? I am new in this field, therefore each advice would be helpful.